# How to insert rich text to excel file from c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a requirement of inserting bold and underlined text to excel file while preserving new line through c# code in windows form application. My function is as below:

```
 private bool insertIntoExcel(string pathname , string sheetname ,int excelRow, int excelColumn,string value) 


 {
        try
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            oXL.Visible = true;

            oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(pathname, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

            //Get all the sheets in the workbook

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;

            //Get the allready exists sheet

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet mWSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item(sheetname);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = mWSheet1.UsedRange;


            mWSheet1.Cells[excelRow, excelColumn] = value;                      

        }catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

this code dosen't preserves new linw, bold, underline and bullets line. How to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: What value are you entering? You need to have char(13)char(10) which is \n\r in your value string to get line break correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if your `value` has '\n' or `Environment.NewLine` maybe you can split it by these characters:

For example:

```
    string[] newLineChars = { "\n", Environment.NewLine};

    string[] splittedVals = value.Split(newLineChars, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (string val in splittedVals)
    {
        mWSheet1.Cells[excelRow, excelColumn] += val;   
    }
```